# Can you run an ASP.NET MVC application from its project folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, build

In IIS 5.1, I have setup a website to point to my ASP.NET MVC project directory, and I get a "Service Unavailable" error when I try to access it after building the project. It seems I have to publish the site to a separate directory and point IIS to the published version to get it to work.

I have already tried "`aspnet_regiis`" but that did not fix the issue. I have also setup wildcard mapping so all requests are sent through the ASP.NET pipeline.

I'm not sure why I would have to publish the files in order to view them. The published version appears to only remove unnecessary files, but the published files seem to be identical to the ones in the actual project directory.

Do you have to publish an ASP.NET MVC website to a different directory in order for IIS to serve it?

Ideally, I would want to set it up such that all I have to do is build the project, and I can immediately view the updated website by visiting `localhost`.

#### Update:

The version is set to 2.0, and when I get home I will check if the `IUSR` account has sufficient privileges. I can't imagine why it wouldn't because the published folder apparently had them by default.

#### Update #2:

The errors in the event log are:

> Failed to initialize the AppDomain:/LM/W3SVC/1/Root
>
> Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException
>
> Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

and

> Failed to execute the request because the ASP.NET process identity does not have read permissions to the global assembly cache. Error: 0x80070005 Access is denied.

I have given the `MY_MACHINE\ASPNET` account "Act as operating system" privileges and I still get this error.

#### Update #3:

So this is interesting... I have XP Media Center Edition, so I forgot I don't have a security tab to verify permissions.

I decided to copy and paste the entire solution into a newly created folder and it works perfectly. This indicates that it's a permission issue but not with the `ASPNET` user. I will try to activate the Security tab and make a 4th (and hopefully final) update.

#### Update #4:

It turns out that when I copied the directory, the permissions changed to allow Everyone access to it. When I checked the original project directory, the `ASPNET` user was not granted any permissions in the directory.

The simple solution was to grant the `ASPNET` user read privileges on the project directory.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right version of asp? Every time I've gotten the Service Unavailable error it was because I forgot to switch from ASP.Net 1.1 to 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problems at all. I've been running an MVC app on IIS5.1 for 6 moths while developing it.

First off check the version of ASP.Net used for your site.

If that isn't the problem check that the user account used to run your website has permissions to the directory and all the files and folders contained within it and make sure that the network service has permissions.

take a look at this link - which might help:
http://weblogs.asp.net/bdesmond/archive/2003/09/20/28441.aspx

Comment: +1 - Right on, the directory didn't have permission for the `ASPNET` account

Comment: Hi. I have the same problem, but still can't publish my MVC at localhost. i checked the AppPool user - NETWORK_SETVICE, added permissions for the folder (actually even to "Everyone" user group) - still same error in event log, and empty page. my publish location is the root of IIS - c:\inetpub\wwwroot. Any ideas?